# Trino throw 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServices.getAdmin() exception,

Tags: hadoop, hbase, trino

I try to fetch some data with Trino which uses the phoenix as connector but I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServices.getAdmin()'
   at io.trino.plugin.phoenix.PhoenixClient.getTableProperties(PhoenixClient.java:568)
   at io.trino.plugin.phoenix.PhoenixMetadata.getTableMetadata(PhoenixMetadata.java:98)
   at io.trino.plugin.phoenix.PhoenixMetadata.getTableMetadata(PhoenixMetadata.java:88)
   at io.trino.plugin.jdbc.JdbcMetadata.lambda$listTableColumns$4(JdbcMetadata.java:371)
   at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
   at io.trino.plugin.jdbc.JdbcMetadata.listTableColumns(JdbcMetadata.java:371)
   at io.trino.plugin.base.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.listTableColumns(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.java:272)
   at io.trino.metadata.MetadataManager.listTableColumns(MetadataManager.java:607)
   at io.trino.metadata.MetadataListing.listTableColumns(MetadataListing.java:135)
   at io.trino.connector.informationschema.InformationSchemaPageSource.addColumnsRecords(InformationSchemaPageSource.java:251)
   at io.trino.connector.informationschema.InformationSchemaPageSource.buildPages(InformationSchemaPageSource.java:216)
   at io.trino.connector.informationschema.InformationSchemaPageSource.getNextPage(InformationSchemaPageSource.java:183)
   at io.trino.operator.ScanFilterAndProjectOperator$ConnectorPageSourceToPages.process(ScanFilterAndProjectOperator.java:376)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:221)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$YieldingProcess.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:181)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:306)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:306)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:306)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:221)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$processStateMonitor$2(WorkProcessorUtils.java:200)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$flatten$6(WorkProcessorUtils.java:277)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:319)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:306)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:221)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$processStateMonitor$2(WorkProcessorUtils.java:200)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:221)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$finishWhen$3(WorkProcessorUtils.java:215)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:372)
   at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorSourceOperatorAdapter.getOutput(WorkProcessorSourceOperatorAdapter.java:149)
   at io.trino.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:387)
   at io.trino.operator.Driver.lambda$processFor$9(Driver.java:291)
   at io.trino.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:683)
   at io.trino.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:284)
   at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:1076)
   at io.trino.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:163)
   at io.trino.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:484)
   at io.trino.$gen.Trino_352____20210213_131405_2.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I use HBase 2.3.4 and Hadoop 3.2.2 and Phoenix 5.1.0

I also copy the right version of Phoenix client to /path/to/trino/plugin and its server to /path/to/HBase/lib/

I have to mention that trino can create table or show the schema's contents but I can not use `select` or `describe` queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trino Phoenix connector does not support Phoenix 5.x yet.
There is an issue about this https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/1271 which you can track. There is also a PR https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/6865 which you can try out yourself.